# How to avoid having 10 switch cases in java?

Tags: java, appium

I am trying to minimise below 10 switch case but after trying few times I am not able to. Can somebody suggest what should I do?

Thanks in advance.

```
 private int getCode(String digit) {

    int keycode = 0;

    switch (digit) {
        case "0":
            keycode = AndroidKeyCode.KEYCODE_0;
        break;

        case "1":
            keycode = AndroidKeyCode.KEYCODE_1;
        break;

        case "2":
            keycode = AndroidKeyCode.KEYCODE_2;
        break;

        case "3":
            keycode = AndroidKeyCode.KEYCODE_3;
        break;
    }

    return keycode;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: This post also has a nice way: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/74743/long-switch-statement-to-lookup-fifty-something-commands

Comment: I'm not sure that duplicate question has the exact answer the OP is looking for, namely `return (int)digit.charAt(0)-'0'+AndroidKeyCode.KEYCODE_0;` (after checking for null and garbage inputs, of course).

Answer (score -2):

Use reflection API. [example](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/class_getfield.htm)
If you are using proguard you must write proguard rules too or disable proguard.